# open window after one cycle of progressbar tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to open the commented file after one cycle of progressbar, can't able to understand the solution given on internet, as my code is simple, so simple answer is required because I am very much beginner in Tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import Label
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry('350x215')
root.title("WELCOME")
root.configure(bg='skyblue')
label1=Label(root,text="Spam Checker",font= 
('Constantia',30),bg='skyblue').place(x=50,y=50)

label2=Label(root,text="(ML Approach)",font= 
(None,16),bg='skyblue').place(x=100,y=100)

pb = ttk.Progressbar(root,length=350, orient='horizontal', 
mode='determinate')
pb.place(y=190) 
pb.maximum=100

pb.start()

""""def openwindow():

     with open('main1.py') as source_file:
        `enter code here`exec(source_file.read())
"""
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to associate a variable with your ProgressBar:

```
progress_var = IntVar()
pb = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=350, variable=progress_var)
```

Then you can use the `trace` method to run a function every time the progress bar is updated, as explained [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).

When the progress bar reaches 100, its value gets reset to 0. So when the function detects that the value is 0, it stops the progress bar and calls the `openwindow` function:

```
def on_progress_bar_updated(*args):
    # when the progress bar reaches 100, it wraps around to 0
    if progress_var.get() == 0:
        pb.stop()
        openwindow()

progress_var.trace('w', on_progress_bar_updated)

pb.start()
```